# How to create variable columns in MYSQL table using python

Tags: python, mysql

How to create variable columns in a table according to the user input?

In other words, I have a table that contains the ID of students, but I need to create variable columns for weeks according to user's choice. For example if the number of weeks chosen by the user is 2 then we create a table like this

```
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE Attendance
        (

        Week1 int,
        Week2 int,
        ID int primary key ,

        )""")
```

Comment: Is this a homework exercise? It sounds a bit like homework

Comment: No it is not a homework  , i am just practising MYSQL using python ( i am a beginner) . If you know how to create a table that have dynamic columns (depending on the user's choice) using python, just post it . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can just build the column defs as a string in Python:

```
num_weeks = 4
week_column_defs = ', '.join("Week{} int".format(week_num) for week_num in range(1, num_weeks+1))
command = """CREATE TABLE Attendance
(

    {weeks} ,
    ID int primary key ,

)""".format(weeks=week_column_defs)

cur.execute(command)
```